# Store array with parse and use it to filter result

Tags: ios, filter, parse-platform

Hi Im creating an app where the user can choose between a set of 20 tags when creating their account. The tags they select are stored in an array in the User class. I also have a class with group chats and i want to load the group-chats according to the tags the user choose upon signing in. I understand that I need to use the .wherekey to filter the result. My idea is to access the current users "tags-array" and then use that to filter the result. The backend Im using is parse.com

Comment: Ok, good idea, go and try it :) (you haven't actually asked a question here, if it doesn't work show your code and ask questions about it).

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps to meet your requirements -

1) While user is in process of profile creation -
1.1) Add the user selected tags to the NSMutableArray.
1.2) Save the tags list to the users data(server/ cloud).

2) After the user signs in 
2.1) Load the group chats according to the above tags in the list.

Example source -

```
- (NSArray *)filterObjects:(NSArray *)objects withTags:(NSArray *)tags
 {
  return [objects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tags IN %@", tag]];
}

// given that the 'objects' array is what you get from server
  NSArray *objects = @[
                       @{@"id" : @"1A", @"tag" : @"1"},
                       @{@"id" : @"2A", @"tag" : @"2"},
                       @{@"id" : @"3A", @"tag" : @"3"},
                       @{@"id" : @"1B", @"tag" : @"4"},
                       @{@"id" : @"2B", @"tag" : @"5"},
                       @{@"id" : @"3B", @"tag" : @"6"}
                       ];

  NSArray *filteredObjects = [self filterObjects:objects withTags:@[@"1", @"3", @"4"]];
  NSLog(@"filteredObjects: %@", filteredObjects); // prints them out as dictionaries
```